# Xamarin iOS Native linking works on Simulator, duplicate Symbols on Device

Tags: c++, ios, gcc, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to link complicated native project for Xamarin. It's Obj-C UI Project that depends on Native Obc-C++ wrapper over c++ library (this is embedded project):
[image]

I have native source and test project in Xcode and everything goes fine.

Then I make fat libraries of all dependencies, add them to xamarin binding project.

[image]

In main project i had to setup gcc options same for simulator and device:

```
-vvvv -cxx --registrar:static -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir}/../RMSDKWrapper -dead_strip -lstdc++ -lstdc++.6.0.9 -lpthread -lsqlite3 -lxml2 -ObjC -ladept-iOS -lxml-iOS -lz -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -ldp-iOS -lePub3-iOS -L/usr/lib -I/usr/include/libxml2"
```

Everything works fine on Simulator but when i'm trying to compile this for Device, linker can't link libs because of duplicate symbols. I checked all libs using 'nm' all objects are looking the same for Simulator and Device.
I saw that only objects that duplicated is Obj-C++ classes in embedded wrapper (rmsdk_wrapper2.xcodeproj). `nm` finds that objects in wrapper lib and in lib from host project(TestRMSD.xcodeproj). But for simulator it resolves well, neither for device.

**UPD**
XS Version:
https://gist.github.com/ad1Dima/eb1cc390930e191a5454260da2410c91

Build Log:
https://gist.github.com/ad1Dima/8ea8c4a271ef63efb310252234b32ae5

I need any idea how can i solve this problem.

Comment: Could you share the full [build log](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1675684-where-can-i-find-my-version-information-and-logs-#verbose-build-output-logs) when you build for the Device. What version of Xamarin.iOS are you using?

Comment: @Prashant updated my question

Comment: Can you confirm if changing your Linker setting in the iOS Build -> Linker Behavior makes an difference? i.e. Link All

Comment: You can share your source code out of it ?

Comment: @ylgwhyh whole project? unfortunately no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move all native code in one XCode project to solve this issue. So i have one lib and no linking errors on device.

But i didn't understand what was wrong with linker.

Comment: Hey, I'm having a very similar problem... If I may ask: By "move all native code in one project" do you mean you moved all native references to a single binding project?

Comment: @nmilcoff if it still a problem - I moved all native dependences into one Xcode project and imported only few screens from it.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons for this error:

- The same native library is included twice.
- Two distinct native libraries happen to define the same symbols.
- A native library is not correctly built, and contains the same symbol more than once.

You can find the troubleshooting steps for the linking errors here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors/#MT5212

Comment: As I mentioned in question. `nm` shows RMSDKSettings.o in both AllbraryReader.a and librmsdk_wrapper2_iOS.a both for simulator libs and for device. But simulator linking works great, device - not.

However RMSDKSettings is added only in rmsdk_wrapper

Comment: @ad1Dima Did any of the workarounds mentioned in the docs help you to resolve the issue? For example, using `-gcc_flags -dead_strip` flag

Comment: in Question and build logs you can see `-dead_strip` and `-gcc_flags`, and all other mtouch flags. They are same for simulator and device.